# Typescript UnitTests with Karma and Mocha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, karma-mocha

I'm trying to implement unit tests for my code by using 
Karma + karma-typescript + mocha.

The following code is based on this [example](https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript/tree/master/examples/angularjs).
The only differences are that I use mocha instead of jasmine and amd instead of commonjs.

**The directory structure**

```
.
|-- src
|   |-- core
|   |   |-- Class1.ts
..
|-- test
|   |-- Test.spec.ts
..
| -- karma.conf.js
| -- tsconfig.json
```

**Karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ["mocha", "karma-typescript"],

        files: [
            {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts'},
            {pattern: 'test/**/*.spec.ts'}
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'src/**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript']
        },

        karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"
        },

        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeNoSandbox: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        },

        reporters: ['karma-typescript'],

        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        browsers: ["ChromeNoSandbox"],

        singleRun: true
    })
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

**And a really simple test**

```
describe("Test", () => {
    it("Should do some cool stuff", () => {
       console.log('Cool stuff');
    })
});
```

Executing karma results in this warning:

```
"Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit"
```

I think that using amd instead of commonjs may cause the problem but I have no idea why.